# C# checking word lengths

Tags: c#

How would I check the length of each word in a string and if one is larger than say 10 display a different response?

Semi Psuedo

```
string allwords= "This is a test this is a test aaaaaaaaaaa this is a test";

if (allwords.Length < 10) {
      Console.WriteLine (allwords.Length);

}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine ("Woahh there one of these words is more than 10 chars");
}
```

Comment: use `split` and test each item returned in the array for it's length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in 4 different ways.
just remember to add

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
```

namespaces to your project.

**1st way**: using Any method and if statement

```
string allwords = "This is a test this is a test aaaaaaaaaaa this is a test ";
bool c = allwords.Split().Any(s => s.Length > 10);
if (c == false)
    Console.WriteLine(allwords);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Woahh there one of these words is more than 10 chars");
```

**2nd way**: using Any method and ? operator

```
string allwords = "This is a test this is a test aaaaaaaaaaa this is a test ";
bool c = allwords.Split().Any(s => s.Length > 10);
Console.WriteLine(c == false ? allwords : "Woahh there one of these words is more than 10 chars");
```

**3rd way**: using string[] and foreach and if statement

```
string allwords = "This is a test this is a test aaaaaaaaaaa this is a test ";
string[] c = allwords.Split();
bool moreThanten = false;
foreach (string v in c)
    if (v.Length > 10)
        moreThanten = true;
if (moreThanten == false)
    Console.WriteLine(allwords);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Woahh there one of these words is more than 10 chars");
```

**4th way**:using string[] and foreach and ? operator

```
string allwords = "This is a test this is a test aaaaaaaaaaa this is a test ";
string[] c = allwords.Split();
bool moreThanten = false;
foreach (string v in c)
    if (v.Length > 10)
        moreThanten = true;
Console.WriteLine(moreThanten == false ? allwords : "Woahh there one of these words is more than 10 chars");
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like:

```
allWords.Split(' ').Any(w => w.Length > 10);
```